# Why an instance of class MqttClient must be enclosed by try/catch?

Tags: java, mqtt, iot, paho

I'm trying to figure it out. I have this line of code:

```
MqttClient Client = new MqttClient(Broker, ClientId, Persistence);
```

But shows an **"Unhandled exception"** error. So I fixed it by enclosing it with a try/catch.

```
 try {
        MqttClient Client = new MqttClient(Broker, ClientId, Persistence);
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It actually works but can't understand why the need of this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: as per javadocs *Throws:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - if the URI does not start with "tcp://", "ssl://" or "local://".
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - if the clientId is null or is greater than 65535 characters in length
MqttException - if any other problem was encountered*

Answer (score 3):

The *instance* doesn't need to be surrounded by `try/catch`, but the *constructor invocation* does, or else needs to be within a method that is declared to throw that exception.

Answer (score -1):

As hinted by some answers. I checked the class definition where are the following constructors:

```
public MqttClient(String serverURI, String clientId) throws MqttException {
    this(serverURI,clientId, new MqttDefaultFilePersistence());
}

public MqttClient(String serverURI, String clientId, MqttClientPersistence persistence) throws MqttException {
    aClient = new MqttAsyncClient(serverURI, clientId, persistence);
}
```

Both throw MqttException which is another class that extends Exception. Thank you so much.

Comment: '*Hinted* by some answers'. Come off it. *Explicitly stated* by both answers and comments.